# Pigpio setting mode to BCM or BOARD

Tags: pigpio

Is there any option in pigpio library that sets pinout mode as BCM or BOARD ? 
I decided that in pigpio default is BCM but in RPi.GPIO there is an option to change that like

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
```

or

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
```

so i wanted to know if it is available in pigpio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pigpio only accepts BCM numbering.

Of course you could always write a Python function to convert from BOARD numbering to BCM.  For the 40 pin Pis the following would work.

```py
BOARD2BCM=[
   -1, -1,  2, -1,  3, -1,  4, 14,
   -1, 15, 17, 18, 27, -1, 22, 23,
   -1, 24, 10, -1,  9, 25, 11,  8,
   -1,  7,  0,  1,  5, -1,  6, 12,
   13, -1, 19, 16, 26, 20, -1, 21]

def Board_to_BCM(pin):
   if pin < 1 or pin > 40:
      return -1
   else:
      return BOARD2BCM[pin-1]
```